# Can I see if an installed app has registered a URI scheme?

Tags: applications

I have an app installed, I'd like to know if I can see if it has registered a custom URI scheme (so it can be opened by other apps and the browser) and if so what the scheme is (e.g. someapp://)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Apps > Configure Apps (Cog in top right) > Opening Links

[YouTube video walkthrough on Android N](https://youtu.be/j30olN1Pg5o)